# Copy script to destination before running

Tags: pycharm

I have a python script that needs to be in a particular place to work correctly (i.e. it gets a path from `os.path.dirname(self._execPath)` and uses it to construct other paths to files that should be available relative to the script's path). However, it happens that that path is in an install directory that my cmake/make install process generates. So if I open the script file in my source directory in PyCharm, I can't execute it because it is not in the install path. My current "solution" is to just do the `make install` once, then open the `install/myscript.py` in PyCharm, edit, run, edit, run, ... then copy the file back to `source/myscript.py`. This is not desirable, because other procedures could accidentally wipe out changes in the install directory, we may forget to copy the file back to the source directory before committing, etc.

Is there any way to have PyCharm copy the file somewhere before running it (with Run -> Run)? Or is there a different solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

One idea:  Make a python script that copies the file to its destination.  Then make a compound run/debug configuration that runs the copy script, then executes your other script.